# How to get an image in the bottom corner of my screen on every page

Tags: magento-1.9, image

I want a little image to appear for certain customer groups when they are logged in. this image has to appear at the bottom right hand corner of every page. For example the google certied logo on http://ao.com/ does anybody know how to do this is magento? I know how to make a check to see if the customer is logged in. However i do not know how to display the image or even what file it should be put in or to make a new one.

If someone could help me that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sticky+footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to do. If you want to float an image to the bottom left you would use this CSS:

```
.badge {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:80px;
  height: 80px;    
}
```

You'll want to create this .badge element (`<div class="badge">`) somewhere on the site and place the css in your own override css.

Here's a bin if you want to see it in action:

http://jsbin.com/bewey/1/edit

Comment: thank you i will give it a go and once i get it working i will accept your answer, thank you

Comment: could i wrap the div in an if statement so it only shows if a certain customer group is logged in?

Comment: i have accepted as it works without the IF statement but if that is possible could you let me know please. Thank you

Comment: Dont worry i did it. But thank you for your help :)